# android sensortag azimuth for compass isn't working (java code)

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, sensors, compass

I am using **Sensortag cc2541** as a sensor connected to a NEXUX 5 through bluetooth.
So the code below doesn't have the typical `onSensorChanged` since it ISN'T using the sensors of the phone itself. Instead, it uses the methods of the sensortag cc2541.

I want to make a simple compass and did some research and came up with the following.

From what I've read on the internet, **Azimuth** should be the direction (around Z) of the compass. 
However, I do not get the correct reading.

I've also included pictures that shows the orientation of `accelerometer` and `magnetometer` of the sensor.

**Accelerometer Orientation**

[image: Accelerometer]

**Magnetometer Orientation**

[image: Magnetometer]

Code

```java
public class ManagerListener extends SensorTagLoggerListener implements SensorTagListener {

    private float[] gravityData = new float[3];
    private float[] geomagneticData  = new float[3];
    private double azimuth,pitch,roll;

    @Override
    public void onUpdateAccelerometer(SensorTagManager mgr, Point3D acc) {
        super.onUpdateAccelerometer(mgr, acc);

        gravityData[0] = (float)acc.x;
        gravityData[1] = (float)acc.y;
        gravityData[2] = (float)acc.z;

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpdateMagnetometer(SensorTagManager mgr, Point3D b) {
        super.onUpdateMagnetometer(mgr, b);

        geomagneticData[0] = (float) -b.y;
        geomagneticData[1] = (float) b.x;
        geomagneticData[2] = (float) -b.z;

        float I[] = new float[9];
        float R[] = new float[9];
        boolean success = SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(R, I, gravityData, geomagneticData);

        if (success)
        {
            float orientationMatrix[] = new float[3];
            SensorManager.getOrientation(R, orientationMatrix);
            azimuth = Math.toDegrees(orientationMatrix[0]);
            pitch = Math.toDegrees(orientationMatrix[1]);
            roll = Math.toDegrees(orientationMatrix[2]);
        }

        final float rotation = (float) azimuth;
        final String xyz = "Azimuth:\t" + String.valueOf(Math.round(azimuth)) + 
                           "\nPitch:\t" + String.valueOf(Math.round(pitch)) + 
                           "\nRoll:\t" + String.valueOf(Math.round(roll));

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                degree.setText(xyz);
                pointer.setRotation(rotation);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

The functions `onUpdateAccelerometer` and `onUpdateMagnetometer` are override of the sensor tag library. That's not the problem. Its what inside the problem.

also, both magnetometer and accelerometer get values every 100 ms.

---

I am trying to do a SIMPLE compass. The only difference between my app and normal compass is that I have to use the SensorTag and its library. I have put the code. There are methods like onUpdateAccelerometer etc... these methods are self explanatory. Point3D has x,y,z as fields. degree and pointer are just text to display and compass image to rotate. Please take a look at this simple and short app that I've found on the internet https://www.sendspace.com/file/62ubk7 I want something similar to this but with the libraries of my sensorTag. Ive put what I've done so far and I did A LOT of research. If someone can help me find where my mistake is, I would gladly give them the bounties.

Comment: And which library are you using to communicate with the SensorTag?

Comment: Oh the code I've posted ignores the SensorTag initial setup. I use the SensorTag's provided libraries which are `BluetoothDevice`,`SensorTagManager`, `SensorTagListener`.

Comment: I'm not clear what the actual problem is. So, here's a couple of questions: 

1) Are you getting data from the device? Eg: You see changing values if you dump the variables "acc" and "b" to logcat.

2) If you use the sensors built into the Nexus 5, does your compass software work? Ie: It's definitely a problem with the external device.

Comment: It would help if you define 'correct reading' if you are getting values from the SensorTag. When I tried the TI Bluetooth SensorTag app I see readings when I rotate the tag which has 1.3.1 firmware.